# Visual Basic Health Dues

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm not getting any errors and the web application is opening as intended in visual studio. I'm writing in Visual Basic. However, when I click the calculate button, there is no calculation. Everything is writting in the event "when clicked" so I'm not sure why I'm getting no calculation.

```
Dim addFee As Integer
Dim monthlyDues As Integer
Dim basicFee As Integer

If chkGolf.Checked = True Then
    addFee += 35
End If
If chkTennis.Checked = True Then
    addFee += 30
End If
If chkRac.Checked = True Then
    addFee += 20
End If
monthlyDues = Val(addFee) + Val(basicFee)
```

It should add all the amounts together from the check boxes and then display the total fees in the monthly dues text box(converted to integer)

Comment: You mean VB.NET not VBA right?

Comment: you don't seem to be using basicFee, how are you deploying this web app?

Comment: *"It should [...] display the total fees in the monthly dues text box"*. And where exactly in that code are you displaying anything in a `TextBox`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be assigning the value of the result to the text of the textbox.

```
 monthlyDues = Val(addFee) + Val(basicFee)
 yourTextbox.Text  = monthlyDues.ToString()
```